# Modify request data before view functions in Flask API

Tags: python, json, flask, request

Is it an allowed pattern in Flask to modify request json data before the view functions (e.g. in a decorator)? Is it even possible? Imagining something like this:

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import request, current_app

def my_function_decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        req = request.get_json()
        # do something to calculate the new value
        req["new key"] = "new value"
        request.set_json(req)

        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorated_function
```

The purpose is to have lat lon data geocoded from a third party service, based on address data that is sent to my service. Not sure if decorators are the right choice for this, or if it is before_request, or something else, or nothing at all.

Comment: Why do you need to manipulate the JSON? You could just pass in the extra information as another argument to the function. Or set information on the `g` shared state object.

Comment: But if you want to, knock yourself out. Manipulating the Werkzeug request body is not trivial, however. You probably would be better off studying the [Werkzeug middleware components](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/middleware/) and then build your own middleware to do your thing. See https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/tree/0.15.x/src/werkzeug/middleware

Answer (score 17):

I know this is a very old question, but there are people who coming here from google (like me). The answer would be:

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import Flask

from werkzeug.datastructures import ImmutableMultiDict

def my_function_decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        http_args = request.args.to_dict()
        http_args ['Shered Data'] = 'Hi!'

        request.args = ImmutableMultiDict(http_args )

        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorated_function 

server = Flask(__name__)

@server.route('/')
@my_function_decorator
def index():
    #Now, request.args contains your data
    return 'It works! Shared data: %s' % (request.args.get('Shered Data'))

server.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Great tip. I believe you want to pass *args and **kargs into func() as well, and might want to use a different name for the temporary args are augmenting, to avoid shadowing the args parameter.